# Graphing Data with HighchartsPHP (PHP Wrapper)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to graph data using Highcharts; however, instead of rendering a graph it outputs the chart instance to the page:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({"chart":{"renderTo":"chart"},"rangeSelector":{"selected":1},"title":{"text":"Potential Impact"},"series":{"name":"Chart Title","tooltip":{"valueDecimals":2},"data":[[1387284761,1],[1387284762,1],[1387284768,1],[1387284772,1],[1387284775,1],[1387284907,1],[1387284961,1],[1387284972,1],[1387284980,1],[1387285045,1],[1387285172,1],[1387285205,1],[1387285206,1],[1387285268,1],[1387285336,1],[1387285348,1],[1387285507,1],[1387285540,1],[1387285568,1],[1387285654,1]]}});
```

I've tried everything that I have been able to come across online so far and am quite stumped. To my (inexperienced) eye, it looks valid. And, the fact that it's actually displaying that as output in the PHP page, instead of a chart or nothing at all, leads me to believe it's going to be an ID10T error.

HTML:

```
include_once ('../../vendors/HighchartsPHP-master/Highchart.php');

        $chart = new Highchart(Highchart::HIGHSTOCK);
        $chart->chart->renderTo = "chart";
        $chart->rangeSelector->selected = 1;
        $chart->title->text = "Potential Impact";
        $chart->series = array(
                'name' => "Chart Title",
                'tooltip' => array(
                    'valueDecimals' => 2
                ),
                'data' => format_data($q),
        );

        $chart->printScripts();
        //echo '<pre>' . print_r($chart->series->data) . '</pre>';
        echo $chart->render("chart");
     }
    ?>

    <div id="chart" style="width: 340px; height: 240px;"></div>
```

PHP - format_data():

```
function format_data($q) {
    $formatted = array();
    $result = correlate_created_at_with_impact($q); // MySQLi query

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $formatted[] = array(intval($row['date']), intval($row['count']));
    }
    return $formatted;
}
```

I've tried formatting the `$chart->data` attribute in both json, and as an array, but neither have worked. Per another thread, someone mentioned removing the `[]` from `$chart->series[]` (as shown above), but that did not work, either. In theory, this should be showing a simple line chart with the x-axis being the dates (formatted as unix timestamps) and y-axis with the relevant value.

jQuery is loaded (I'm using Bootstrap and it works fine), I've manually added the script calls for highcharts.js, highstock.js, and the exporting.js module to verify they're loaded. They are all loaded and the links resolve.

Ideally, I'd like to use the JS implementation, but I'm far from competent in JS.  I figured I'd knock out the PHP implementation first and go from there...

I'm not sure what else to inspect. Any help and/or insight will greatly be appreciated!

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my script tag and used the code from the demo files and it loaded. It must have been a syntax error somewhere in the script tag.